# “A government of the people, by the people, for the people”

Tags: prepositions, figures-of-speech, politics

From [a famous speech](http://www.ourdocuments.gov/doc.php?flash=true&doc=36&page=transcript):

> A government of the people, by the people, for the people

I believe the last part is clear (*for the people*). But what is the difference— in meaning— between *of the people* (it is a genitive form?) and *by the people*?

As for the question mark ("it is a genitive form?") I think there is no need to set it inside the parentheses.

Comment: Government ***of*** the people - the people are ***the ones who are governed***. Government ***by*** the people - the people are ***the ones doing the governing***. Government ***for*** the people - the people are ***the ones for whose benefit the governance process exists***.

Comment: Note: the source of this phrase is contested, being erroneously attributed to Cleon and Wycliffe, as well as many genuine variants preceding Lincoln (sometimes seen as alternatives rather than simultaneous). Such figures as John Adams, Daniel Webster, and Unitarian thinker Theodore Parker came close, but Lincoln seems to have been first with the precise wording. See Of the People, by the People, for the People, John L. Haney, *Proceedings of the American Philosophical Society*, Vol. 88, No. 5 (Nov. 7, 1944), pp. 359-367. But such speculations are off-topic here.

Comment: With no real knowledge of the backstory, I agree with @FumbleFingers: government **of** the people is govern*ing* of the people, like tending of the garden. The point is that the people govern *themselves* (as a whole).

Comment: @Drew: And crucially, the primary purpose of the governance is ***to benefit the governed*** ("the people"). Not to appease the gods, revive the mammoths, stabilise the money supply, or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Of the people" refers to the government's composition.  It's referring to the fact that the government is made up of people who come from the people.

"By the people" refers to who chooses those people who make up the government.

Essentially, it's saying that it's a government comprised of common people who were chosen by common people.

Comment: So, 'of the people' refers to government's officials, they may come from all citizen.

Comment: Yes, it's pointing to the fact that there is no nobility, no aristocracy, no house of lords, and no king.  There is no special class ruling the country that is set apart from common people.  As all people are just people, neither commoner nor noble, then all people lead, and by election, any person(s) can govern.

Comment: I would disagree slightly in that "government by the people" means that it's "people" (i.e. common people) who are doing the governing (i.e. those in power are common people), and "of the people" means chosen by, and accountable to, the people. So your implications are entirely correct but I think different part of the sentence refer to different things.

Comment: @MichaelBroughton: I do not argue on the statement regarding the court's interpretation. But I think we cannot equalize 'person' and 'people' in the text.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman: And 'by the people' means similar: all the citizens have active voting right (as regards government).

Comment: @Rock: That's what I was saying "by the people" meant. When I said, " 'By the people' refers to who chooses those people who make up the government," I was exactly referring to voters, to "the people" of the US of A. Understand the context: At great human cost, the US had severed herself from the the UK and so had a mandate to clearly differentiate herself and thus answer magnificent sacrifice with those rights and freedoms promised, including the right to vote and freedom to self-govern held "by the people." Even for the House of Commons, the UK only let landed gentry vote, not "the people."

Comment: I disagree with the first sentence here! In context, it seems obvious to me that "Of the people" refers to ***object / "patient"*** of the ***activity*** "government=governance", not the "composition" of the ***organised group*** "the government". And "by the people" means the ***members*** of the government are "the people" (as opposed to career politicians. Freemasons, and other wealthy "Svengalis"). It doesn't necessarily mean "the people" actually ***voted*** for whoever is in the government (though it *might* imply that).

Comment: What @FumbleFingers said. "government of the people" means "governing of the people" - like tending of the garden. The people **are governed** by the people, for the benefit of the people.

Answer (score 5):

*Of the people* refers to the government's target, indicating what is governed.

*Of the people* is not really necessary, but emphasizes the rest of the sentence.

*[B]y the people* indicates that government was designated by the people. It refers to democracy.

*[F]or the people* indicates that the objective of the government is to improve common welfare.

Answer (score 0):

The three pillars of a democracy : Executive, Legislature and Judiciary

Rule By the people: refers to the Executive branch in a democracy  (Law enforcers)

Rule Of the people: Legislative branch  (Law makers)

Rule For the people: Judicial branch ( Law interpreters)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Using the term "the people" to mean all people regardless of how much power and resources they control, maybe it means:

- "government of the people" i.e. the people's government. The people
  OWN the government. The government BELONGS to the people.
- "government by the people" i.e. the people either give permission
  to specific representatives to make governing decisions (in a large
  democracy), or directly make governing decisions themselves. The
  people STEER the government.
- "government for the people" i.e. the point of government is to work
  towards purposes defined by the people. The people's GOALS are served
  by the government.